# how to encrypt / decrypt password with salt using libsodium php

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt, libsodium

What i am trying to get is

- encrypt a password + salt with libsodium
- store it to a database
- read it and decrypt it (getting the plain password back for authentication)

I got a list of salts that i want to use to encrypt / decrypt my password.
When i encrypt the password i get a hash back so that one seems to work but at decrypting i always get false as return value.

Am i using the wrong methods for encrypt / decrypt with libsodium or am i completely driving in the wrong direction?

My source for encrypt / decrypt:

```
function encrypt_libsodium($to_encrypt, $salt_to_use){
        if(!$data || !$salt_to_use){
            return null;
        }

        //get stored salt
        $this->key_ = substr(md5($this->pw_key[$salt_to_use].'_'), 0, $this->ks);

        //some libsodium specific stuff
        $out_len = \Sodium\CRYPTO_SIGN_SEEDBYTES;
        $ops_limit = \Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_SCRYPTSALSA208SHA256_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE;
        $mem_limit =\Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_SCRYPTSALSA208SHA256_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE;

        //create hash using libsodium
        $hash = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash($out_len, $to_encrypt, $this->key_,$ops_limit, $mem_limit);
        return $hash;
    }

    function decrypt_libsodium($hash, $salt_to_use){
        if(!$hash || !$what){
            return null;
        }

        //get stored salt
        $this->key_ = substr(md5($this->pw_key[$salt_to_use].'_'), 0, $this->ks);

        //get verification hash
        $decrypted = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_str_verify($this->key_, $hash);
        return $decrypted;
    }
```

I appreciate any help!

regards Dom

Comment: A HASH is not (supposed) to be reversable, so all you can do is hash the plain text password in the same way and compare the HASH's

Comment: So explain why you need to be able to convert to plaintext for authentication?

Comment: I got a password to authenticate and want to store it in my local db encrypted but i need it plain for the authentication itself.

Comment: Your "local encrypted db" as in something like KeePassX?

Comment: no my db is a simple mysql db. What i meant is to store my encrypted password to the local db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need specifically use libsodium, with this function you should be able to store the data encrypted in the database and decrypt it.

```
define("ENCRYPT_METHOD", "AES-256-CBC");
define("SECRET_KEY","randomtextrandomtextforthesecretkey");
define("SECRET_IV", "randomtextforthesecretiv");
function encriptar($action, $string)
{
  $output = false;
  $key    = hash("sha256", SECRET_KEY);
  $iv     = substr(hash("sha256", SECRET_IV), 0, 16);

  if ($action == "encrypt")
  {
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, ENCRYPT_METHOD, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);
  }
  else if($action == "decrypt")
    {
        $output = base64_decode($string);
        $output = openssl_decrypt($output, ENCRYPT_METHOD, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
  return $output;
}
```

The output will be the data you will store/get to database.

Comment: that could be working for me since all i want to do is to find an updated version of mcrypt because that one got depricated. i wanted to use libsodium because i read many post saying that libsodium is the best way to encrypt/decrypt. i think i'll live with openssl as long as I don't get sodium to work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to mix many unrelated things. `CRYPTO_SIGN_SEEDBYTES` is for signatures, which has nothing to do with password hashing, `crypto_pwhash` doesn't use the scrypt algorithm, so the `CRYPTO_PWHASH_SCRYPTSALSA208SHA256_*` constants don't apply, and I'm not sure what `md5()` does here. And you probably want to hash the password, not to encrypt it.

Anyway, the `crypto_pwhash_str()` function does everything you need. It creates a salt, hashes the password, and encodes the result (along with the salt, the algorithm and its parameters) as a string that you can directly store into the database:

```
$password = 'correct horse battery staple';
$h = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str($password,                                   
         \Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
         \Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE);
```

`$h` is all you need to store in the database.

Then, to verify that what you have in the database is valid for a given password:

```
if (\Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str_verify($h, $password) === FALSE) {
    // wrong password!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that makes things a bit clearer. Is it also possible to decrypt the stored password again? because i would need that for authentication.

Comment: The passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed. It is possible to verify that a given password is the correct one, but given what is in the database, finding the password requires a lot of effort. If the passwords are encrypted instead, a vulnerability in your application may allow attackers to retrieve the entire list of passwords, immediately useable. Please do not store user passwords, even encrypted using a key your application knows about.

Comment: Aye, here you are missing a fundamental understanding of what hashing, encrypting, and password validation mean....

So a hash is a One Way process.

to "authenticate", you take what the user types, and then hash that and compare it with the hashed version of the password in the database. You never want to "decrypt" or "unhash" what is in the database.

The "nonce" means that the specific algorithm for hashing is different for every password in your database. This is good because it stops certain types of attack.